# How to use Java and python in intellij on the same project

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea

I need to use Java and python in the same project, IntelliJ.

When I set up the JDK, the Java code was fine, but the import of the python package failed. On the contrary, python is normal and Java is problematic

IntelliJ is set as follows:

[image],[image],[image],[image]

The python package import failed:

[image]

I see several methods on stack overflow:

I changed the SDK to python3.6 in`Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies->Module SDK`and The Java JDK is still included in the `Project Structure->Project->Project SDK`, but it is useless

I've set up the Python interpreter for the actual Facets and in `Project Structure->Facets` and restart intellij, But it doesn't work

Can I set up python and Java SDK at the same time?

Comment: Java Module + Python Facet is the way to go.

Comment: @CrazyCoder.I tried,but it doesn't work

Comment: I downloaded the sklear-plugin from github, which is a python/Java hybrid project, and tried many approaches. No matter how I set up the SDK, one of python and Java always has a problem

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY and attach a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: git clone https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml-plugin.git.I import the project into intellij.Intellij Settings screenshot was uploaded in the problem above

Comment: We were not able to reproduce the issue with this project in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3. Maven facet persists and Python code [has no errors](https://i.imgur.com/LKx3jbJ.png).

Comment: I wonder if there is something wrong with the setup,You have seen my Settings above. Is there any problem? Whether it depends on the version of each component.Thanks

Comment: The problem can be caused by these packages being missed in the interpreter path you are trying to use (anaconda).

Comment: In ubuntu, the same Settings and code don't have the same problems.Win system, although python import package has red line, it can be used, I don't know why. Thank you.

Comment: Install the required packages into your python path.

Comment: Under Anaconda, all required packages are available, including pandas，sklearn.base

Comment: We can't verify it from the provided screenshots, please contact the support or report the issue in YouTrack to get help.

Answer (score 18):

You need to "Add framework support" / Facets

As long as you already have python installed, just follow this.

Right-click the directory/module/project where you have your python scripts, right at the top you will see "Add framework Support..."

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/adding-support-for-frameworks-and-technologies.html#disable-framework-auto-detection